# Add key to Array using a .each() loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

I'm trying to parse a table with jQuery and populate an array, I've written this code to do this:

```
var comments = new Array();

$("#mytable tr:nth-child(odd)").each( function( index ) {
    comments[index]["url"] = $(this).find(".menu2 a").attr("href");
    comments[index]["name"] = $(this).find(".menu2 a").text(); 
    comments[index]["avatar"] = $(this).find(".menu2 a img").attr("src");
    comments[index]["date"] = $(this).find("td[valign] b:first-child").text();
    $(this).find("td[valign] b:first-child").remove();
    comments[index]["report"] = $(this).find("td[valign] .pcomment_report").attr("data-refid");
    $(this).find("td[valign] .pcomment_report").remove();
    comments[index]["comment"] = $(this).find("td[valign]").html();        
});
```

But it returns me:

> TypeError: Cannot set property 'url' of undefined

How can I make this code works?

Comment: why are you adding named properties to an Array? ED: nvrmind, you don't want to...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The message implies that `comments[index]` is undefined.  You need to create it first:

```
comments[index] = {};
```